# Alternative to qTip (jQuery Tooltip Plugin)

Tags: jquery-plugins

Can anyone recommend a good alternative to qTip, the jQuery tooltip plugin? I feel like it's slowing down my web app because its adding canvas elements and event listeners all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/).

Comment: This worked out beautifully - qTip was out of control in IE6 and simpletip fixed all of the performance issues and kept most of the advanced functionality I needed.

Comment: Check out qTip2. It’s in active development, and it’s pretty rad.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download/

Answer (score 3):

GitHub.com uses **[tipsy](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy)**. I trust that they have chosen pretty carefully, so that's what I would go for.

The [Bootstrap tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) are "inspired" by Tipsy as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jQueryTOOLS](http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/) Tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I had problems with qTip also.
I ended up making my own. This seems to be happening more often. I just can't find what I want and end up making what I need.
https://github.com/donnyv/next-msg

**Plus it has themes**
[image]

Comment: I tried to use your plugin with JQuery 1.4.2 but I have an error message: "this.text is not a function".

Comment: Sorry Donny, I changed to qTip...so I modified my code already. But I just tried again with JQuery 1.4.4 and it works...maybe something was wrong into the previous web page? I don't know because I tried again with another page...I can tell you that it was really simple because I wanted to try your plugin before integrating it into the whole website. Maybe there were some conflicts with other plugins? I used a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Here are 49 alternatives.

http://www.smashingapps.com/2011/12/05/50-awesomely-useful-yet-free-jquery-tooltip-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

don't forget about the **[Jquery UI tooltip](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip)**

And **[Tooltip Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)**

Answer (score 0):

I fount https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster with almost all essential functions of qTip.

The qTip js file is 64kb while this is 17kb. Which was important in our project.